# Convert from unsigned short to string c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

How can I convert from unsigned short to string using C++?
I have tow unsigned short variables:

```
    unsigned short major = 8, minor = 1;
```

I want to join them for on string, looks like:

```
    std::string version = major + "." + minor;
```

how can I do it? will aprrechiate a small sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

could use [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) or [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)(C++11) or boost::lexical_cast

```
#include<sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << major  << "." << minor;

std::string s = ss.str();
```

std::to_string:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(major) + "." +std::to_string(minor);
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, you don't need some stream do do this:

```
std::string version = std::to_string(major)
              + "." + std::to_string(minor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::ostringstream`. You need to include the header `<sstream>`.

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << major << "." << minor;

std::cout << ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << major << "." << minor;
```

Receive the generated string via `oss.str()`.